# how do i use php to read an external file and put insides into variables?

Tags: php, json, variables, external

I had no idea to correctly form the title of this question, because I don't even know if what I'm trying to do has a name.

Let's say I've got an external file (called, for instance, settings.txt) with the following in it:

```
template:'xaddict';
editor:'true';
wysiwyg:'false';
```

These are simple name:value pairs. 
I would like to have php take care of this file in such a way that I end up with php variables with the following values:

```
$template = 'xaddict';
$editor = 'true';
$wysiwyg = 'false';
```

I don't know how many of these variables I'll have.

How should i go and do this?

The data inside the file is in simple name:value pairs. No nesting, no complex data. All the names need to be converted to $name and all the values need to be converted to 'value', disregarding whether it is truly a string or not.

Comment: You've indicated it isn't quite JSON what you're doing, in which case you need to be fairly specific about the format of the file and how complex/nested the data structures can be. If it's just simple name:value pairs, that's one thing, but if its not JSON and it's deeply nested data structures, that's something else.

Comment: It's only name:value pairs. No need for anything more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want 'true' in "editor:'true'" to be interpreted as a string or as a boolean? If sometimes string, sometimes boolean, how do you know which?

If you have "number='9'" do you want '9' interpreted as a string or an as an integer? Would '09' be a decimal number or octal? How about "number='3.14'": string or float? If sometimes one, sometimes the other, how do you know which?

If you have "'" (single quote) inside a value is it escaped? If so, how?

Is there any expectation of array data?

Etc.

Edit: This would be the simplest way, imo, to use your example input to retrieve your example data:

```
$file = 'test.csv';
$fp = fopen($file, 'r');
while ($line = fgetcsv($fp, 1024, ':')) {
    $$line[0] = $line[1];
}
```

Comment: the only stuff in the file will be strings ('xaddict'), numbers ('9' or '9.16') and true/false text values. I'll try to implement a way to turn all values into the ones I desire, but that's not the problem right now. of later concern. Probably I'll turn all numbers into doubles (floats), whether they're decimals or not.

Comment: plus. I found out in php: '9.126' == 9.126. returns true.

Comment: this is perfect. Should've thought about Comma Separated Values in the first place. Thanks bunches!!!

Comment: I'm glad it helped. For the record, though, my questions were intended to nudge you toward considering something like JSON instead. :)

Answer (score 6):

```
$settings = json_decode(file_get_contents($filename));
```

assuming your file is in valid JSON format. If not, you can either massage it so it is or you'll have to use a different approach.

Comment: this way I've got to create a valid JSON file, which means introducing  the {} tags. I'd like to stay away from it.

Answer (score 1):

If you use JSON, you can use something like:

```
extract(json_decode(file_get_contents('settings.json')));
```

Using extract may be dangerous, so I suggest to store these settings in an array:

```
$settings = json_decode(file_get_contents('settings.json'));
```

Comment: this would create the $settings["template"] variable, but I'm trying to create the variable $template. I don't care much about JSON, so if it can be done without... gladly

Comment: Then use the extract function. It can create a security hole, but it does what you want.

Comment: If you don't want to use {} in your file, you can mimic a fake json with extract(json_decode('{'.file_get_contents('settings.json').'}'));

Answer (score 0):

You should read your file to an array, with the file() function, then you should cycle on it: for each line (the file() function will return an array, one line per item), check if the line is not blank, then explode() on the ":" character, trim the pieces, and put them into an array.
You will end up win an array like this:

```
[template] = xaddict
[editor] = true
```

then you can use this information.

Do **not** automatically convert this into local variables: it's a great way to introduce security risks, and potentially very obscure bugs (local variables obscured by those introduced by this parsing).

Comment: is variable variables a solution? like this:
$a = 'template';
$$a = 'xaddict';
echo "$template";
returns 'xaddict'